# Foward any kind of $_POST data in PHP with cURL

Tags: php, post, curl, libcurl

I'm writing a small proxy server for my personal use in PHP.
Fowarding the webpages' requests, I have to foward also the $_POST data, but in general I don't Know what type of data is inside POST.

If the POST contains some form-data this is pretty simple:

```
private function preparePostData() {
    if (count($_POST) > 0) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
        $post = http_build_query($_POST);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work if $_POST contains other types od data ( JSON, files, etc etc).
So I was wondering if exist a general method to foward ANY kind of $_POST data with cURL.

Comment: You have to do conditions for every kind of $_POST i.e. foreach ($_POST as $value) { if ($value //here comes the condition ...

Comment: You could just forward RAW POST data. Not all applications will send var www urlencoded data, some will send raw data. Find out how to forward raw post data (which could very well also be urlencoded) with CURL and have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I'd like a more general method.
And in this case, how I could understand if inside POST there is a file or a JSON ( form data is quite easy, it's an array).